# Why can't a WordPress network (multisite) in it's own folder use subdomains?

Tags: multisite, subdomains

If I'm setting up a brand new multisite installation with WordPress in it's own folder (say /wp/) why can't I configure the network to use subdomains instead of subfolders?

Currently, if I try to setup the network with the WordPress core in it's own folder I'm not allowed to choose between a subdomain-based or sub-folder based network. I must use sub-folders. What are the technical reasons for this?

I've scoured trac and Google for an answer to this question with no luck. A more detailed explanation than what is provided on http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network or http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  The fact is, a network can use subdomains or subfolders, even when WordPress is installed in it's own folder **as long as the main site's HOME URL is set to domain.com and not to the sub folder location**.

**Here's an example:**

I setup a clean install of WordPress using Mark Jaquith's [WordPress Skeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton) which places WordPress's core files at domain.com/wp/. However, when trying to run the initial install script, WordPress chokes on its own redirects. (It keeps trying to load domain.com/wp-admin/install.php instead of domain.com/wp/wp-admin/install.php. Maybe a bug report for another day?)

To get around that, I manually typed in the correct path to the install script (domain.com/wp/wp-admin/network.php). By doing this, WordPress sets the HOME URL to `domain.com/wp` instead of just `domain.com`. (Which makes sense, really.)

By changing the site's HOME URL to `domain.com`, I am now able to choose a subdomain or subfolder installation when setting up the multisite.